# ASCII to HEX convertion in jni getting wrong values

Tags: java, c, encryption, java-native-interface

I think my previous question was not at to the pont.So Iam trying to explain what exactly i want.
"Trying to encrypt data from java   and decrypt at the arduino (c) and viceversa

I have tried many 3des+ecb encryption in java. I was getting different different answer, for different code.So finally, I have decided to use the c code as a library for java using jni and iam  getting correct answer.so at the arduino end also i can use the same "C" code.

Now let me come to the point:

I am sending plain_text from java to "C" using jni(netbeans) there Iam encrypting the data,then "i will receive the encrypted data from c"(prob).Then I will send the data to arduino.DECRYPT the cipher text using c code.Then sending some ENCRYPTed data from arduino by  using c encryption, then at the other end(app) i will decypt and use it.

I think this is cleare.

PROBLEM:
I dont know how to receive correct ciphertext from c.

```
unsigned  char *enc_data_return=(char*)malloc(100);
enc_data_return=tdes_encrypt(32, plain_text, encrypted_text);("tdes_encrypt is the method iam using to encrypt i think that code is not needed here if u want i will send late")
```

when i print the pointer value I am getting correct value in hex of encrypted data (I checked using 3des online tool)

printf("%2x  ",  *(enc_data_return+30));

TDES Ciphertext Block 0:
39  39  85  e3   7  9a  e4  eb
TDES Ciphertext Block 1:
ca  68  61  8f  31  b6  a5   b
TDES Ciphertext Block 2:
7c  ce  23  34  f4  d7  6f  86
TDES Ciphertext Block 3:
c1  9f  c5  8b  a0  c3  d7  82

In hex iam getting exact value of encrypted data but when i convert to jstring iam getting 
99ãäëÊha1¶¥|Î#4ô×o_ŋ Ãׂ
but expected value is
 99ãäëÊha1¶¥|Î#4ô×oÁÅ Ã×
 Iam using below code to get jstring.
 jstring jstrBuf = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,enc_data_return);

i tried with bte array also
  jbyteArray array = (*env)->NewByteArray (env,l);
    (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion (env,array, 0, l, (jbyte*)(enc_data_return));

facing same problem

I dont know how to get encrypted data please help me. Those encrypted data are non ascii or extened ascii. So all converter at the c end and java end giving wrong values.so can i send hex value directly from c end  to java."Its not possible iguess" but if it is tell me if no please give me a solution.

please help me.

Comment: If you just need 3DES use the 3DES cipher integrated in Java.

Comment: Why would you think encrypted data could be represented as a `String`?

Comment: my requirement is I have to encrypt/decrypt data in java and my friend will decrypt/encrypt in c.so first as u told i refered so many code to do 3des +ecb encryption,there are so many program giving me a different encrypted data.so i finally decided to use jni.

Comment: At least i need hexadecimal value of encrypted data from c how to get that.I am currently storing the encrypted data in a pointer.How to pass those values to java,any idea   39  39  85  e3   7  9a  e4  eb  these are my encrypted data.

Comment: ECB is not secure. CBC is even less secure for transport security.

Comment: Java from the beginning maintained Unicode in text. Hence `char` is two bytes and contains UTF-16. And `byte` is the binary data byte. This typically leads to wrong usage coming from C/C++. Binary data should be kept in `byte[]`  otherwise you are converting back and forth using some encoding, and the conversion may fail. Not all byte sequences may be represented in UTF-8 and other pitfalls. As textual String contains chars, ByteArrayOutputStream/ByteArrayInputStream may contain a `byte[]`.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes How so is: "CBC is even less secure for transport security" in and of itself?

Comment: @zaph Attackers can simply change the ciphertext, as with ECB, but on top of that you have to worry about padding oracle attacks, which amount to 128 tries per byte to retrieve the plaintext. You should use an authenticated mode of encryption at the minimum. But switching to TLS, possibly in *pre-shared-key* mode would be preferable to that.

Comment: I said: How is CBC less secure for transport security *in and of itself*. A padding oracle is another issue and she libraries such as Apple's Common Crypto do not even report padding errors to the caller. I agree one should use encryption authentication but that is not a common issue to CBC mode. Sure one can change the cipher text if they can out a MITM attack. again not related to CBC mode. The possibility of authentication with CBC mode is also a possibility. It is the blanket statement: "CBC is even less secure for transport security" (than ECB mode)" that is in error.

Comment: It would be ideal if only cryptographic domain experts implemented encryption but that is in the same category as horses flying. Under those circumstances 99% of the encryption questions on SO would disappear. Also it would be ideal if authentication modes such as AES GCM were readily available on all platforms but that is still way in the future. Even 3DES in this question is very questionable, it should not be used in new work. Most of the libraries still incorrectly specify AES padding as PKCS#5 and then there is mcrypt(), the only good thing about mcrypt is that there are worse options.

Comment: Finally no app encryption on a phone is going to be 100% secure, it is all just a matter of the level of work factor required of the attacker. Even further, lacking hardware such as TPMs, HSMs and hardware encryption the key is available at decryption/ decryption time.

Comment: Thank you I came to knoe lots of things from you guys.

Answer (score 2):

Plaintext input and ciphertext input for 3DES is binary. It's therefore important that you create a library that works on bytes, not on characters. To encode strings you should first perform [character-encoding](/questions/tagged/character-encoding) on the text, creating a binary (byte array) equivalent. UTF-8 should probably be preferred.

It's best to do this in Java, there is no need to do this in C (at your side anyway):

```
"plaintext".toBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

should do the trick.

Now if you want to send the ciphertext as string you'd need to perform [encoding](/questions/tagged/encoding) on the bytes. Best to use base 64 for this, again in Java:

```
Base64.getEncoder().encode(ciphertext);
```

Upon receival you'd therefore first decode the base 64, then decrypt the ciphertext and convert it back to a string by decoding the UTF-8 characters, i.e. the above process in reverse.

---

If you do not encoding correctly you may loose data in transit. For instance, control characters could be filtered out of the ciphertext and unknown characters may be dropped or converted into replacement characters.

Unless you are certain that your input is ASCII the same thing may happen when directly using strings as bytes. If you use a character higher than 126 (127 is reserved) you may run into trouble.

This is likely your current problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I will check, if dont get answer I may ask questions again please be with me support me thank you.

Comment: As u said I tried to send byte data from native to java

Comment: I am trying to do as you said.I am sending char data from native to java. I am storing the encrypted data in a pointer, in c------>  unsigned  char *enc_data_return=(char*)malloc(100);    ------>enc_data_return=tdes_encrypt(32, plain_text, encrypted_text);   printf("%2x  ",  *(enc_data_return+31)); i can print all values in hex correctly, of encrypted data in c. so last value of encrypted data is   hex value is 8b .

Comment: I receved this data in java as  then as you said i converted to bytes ----> System.out.println("Hai data here "+new DesJava().toHex("".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))); getting out put c28b I want only 8b.(I am unable to print that encrypted data its taking as space I think you got my prob if not please ask i will try to explain clearly please reply)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i Found answer for my Question Im posting answer becuase it may help to other.Convertion from char* to jstring or jbytearray gives wrong answer for the encrypted data.So its Better to take hex value of thoose values.What i did means i just converted to jintarray and passed intarray of encrypted data I am receiving correct answer .